# How to scan all nearby ibeacons using coordova based Hybrid application?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ibeacon, hybrid-mobile-app

I am planning to develop a hybrid application that will scan ibeacons , can you please point me to right cordova plugin that has this facility?

I was referring to [petermetz/cordova](https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon), but it seems it doesn't have scan facility

I am NOT using Angular JS, so please don't refer to ng plugins

Thanks,

Rohit

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **the [cordova-plugin-ibeacon](https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon) is the one to use.**  It does support scanning for beacons, although the examples don't make this obvious.  Check out the "Start ranging a single iBeacon" example.  The only difference between looking for a single beacon and lots of beacons is that you set the identifiers to null to look for any identifier as a wildcard.  Like this:

`var beaconRegion = new cordova.plugins.locationManager.BeaconRegion(identifier, uuid, null, null);`

The line above will set up a region that you can use to find any major and minor value for a beacon with the specified ProximityUUID.

This brings up an important distinction between Android and iOS.  On iOS, you *must* supply a ProximityUUID (the second parameter to the method shown) and it is impossible to scan for all beacons regardless of ProximityUUID.  On Android, you *can* supply null for that parameter, effectively allowing you to scan for any beacon.  To be clear, this is not a plugin-specific limitation on iOS.  It is an operating system limitation.

Comment: I tried following on android var beaconRegion = new cordova.plugins.locationManager.BeaconRegion(identifier, 0, 0, 0); but it is throwing exception BeaconRegion.js:69 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: uuid.match is not a function
    at Function.BeaconRegion.isValidUuid (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/com.unarin.cordova.beacon/www/model/BeaconRegion.js:69:14)
    at Function.BeaconRegion.checkUuid (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/com.unarin.cordova.beacon/www/model/BeaconRegion.js:77:20)
    at new BeaconRegion

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the plugin validates that the UUID not be null when declaring a region.

Comment: so is there a way to fetch uuid of beacons ?